# API Карт: длинна маршрута

Tags: api, карты

Есть-ли `API` для каких-либо карт, которые позволяют задать координаты двух точек и получить длину маршрута между этими точками в `json` формате?

Нужны именно данные о маршруте, выводить на карту сам маршрут не нужно. В API Yandex карт, получить сами данные маршрута не получилось, да и их политика не позволяет это делать (нужно выводить все на карту, если не ошибаюсь).

Нашел такую возможность в API Sputnik Maps, но там доступ закрыт (CORS).

Пример:
    http://routes.maps.sputnik.ru/osrm/router/viaroute?loc=52.503033,13.420526&loc=52.516582,13.429290&instructions=true

Comment: с учетом топологии или же по эллипсоиду?

Comment: проблему с cors можно решить проксированием

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо за совет, попробовал через https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/, сработало